# C++ Numeric values are not printing correctly

Tags: c++11, double, decimal

Main Program

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "pizza.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {

    menuItem item;
menu:
    item.getMenu();//Menu Prompt

    cout << "\nI would like number: " << flush;
    int menuChoice;
    cin >> menuChoice;
    while (menuChoice < 1 || menuChoice > 3) {
        cout << "\nINVAILD INPUT:\nEnter a Value that corresponds with your menu choice" << endl;
    }
    if (menuChoice == 1) {
        item.getPizza();
    }
    if (menuChoice == 2) {
        item.getSandwhich();
    }
    if (menuChoice == 3) {
        item.getSide();
    }
    int ready4checkout;
    cout << "\n\n~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~" << endl;
    cout << "\nAre you ready to checkout?\n" << endl;
    cout << "checkout = 1\nAdd to the order = 2" << endl;
    cout << "\nI would like to:" << flush;
    cin >> ready4checkout;
    if (ready4checkout == 1) {
        item.addcheckout();
    }
    if (ready4checkout == 2) {
        goto menu;
    }
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}
```

Header File

```
#include<iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class menuItem {
protected:
    float smallPizza = 5.99;
    float mediumPizza = 6.99;
    float largePizza = 9.99;
    float halfSandwhich = 6.00;
    float wholeSandwhich = 8.00;
    float bonelessWings = .70;
    float breadStix = 4.99;

public:
    float checkout;
    float pizzaCheck;
    float sandCheck;
    float sideCheck;

    menuItem item(float smallPizza, float mediumPizza, float largePizza, float halfSandwhich, float wholeSandwhich, float bonelessWings, float breadStix,float checkout);


    string getMenu() {
        string menu;
        cout << "~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~ Welcome to Pizza Italiano! ~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~\n\n" << endl;
        cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Main Menu ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" << endl;
        cout << "Enter the value of the food that you wish to devour:\n" << endl;
        cout << "\n1.Pizza\n2.Sandwhich\n3.Appetizer" << endl;
        return menu;
    }

    string getPizza() {
        float pizzaCheck;
        string pizza;
        float pizzaSize;
pizza:
        cout << " \n~~~~~~ How would you like your pizza made? ~~~~~~\n" << endl;
        cout << "   Size" << endl;
        cout << "-----------" << endl;
        cout << "1. Large                 $9.99 \n2. Medium                $6.99 \n3. Small                 $5.99" << endl;
        cout << "\nI would like the number: " << flush;
        cin >> pizzaSize;
        cin.ignore();
        while (pizzaSize < 1 || pizzaSize > 3) {
            cout << "\nINVAILD INPUT:\nEnter a Value that corresponds with your menu choice" << endl;
            goto pizza;
        }
        if(pizzaSize == 1) {
            cout << "\n****You have selected a Large pizza****" << endl;
            pizzaCheck = pizzaSize;
            pizzaCheck = largePizza + pizzaCheck;
        } else if(pizzaSize == 2) {
            cout << "\n****You have selected a Medium Pizza****" << endl;
            pizzaCheck = pizzaSize;
            pizzaCheck = mediumPizza + pizzaCheck;
        } else {
            cout << "\n****You have selected a Personal pizza****" << endl;
            pizzaCheck = pizzaSize;
            pizzaCheck = smallPizza + pizzaCheck;
        }
        cin.get();
        return pizza;
    }
    string getSandwhich() {
        string sandwhich;
        float sandSize;
Sandwhich:
        cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~ What size would you like your sandwhich to be? ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n" << endl;
        cout << "1. Six inch             $6.00\n2. Twelve inch           $8.00" << endl;
        cout << "I would like number:" << flush;
        cin >> sandSize;
        while (sandSize < 1 || sandSize > 2) {
            cout << "\nINVAILD INPUT:\nEnter a Value that corresponds with your menu choice" << endl;
            goto Sandwhich;
        }
        if (sandSize == 1) {
            cout << "**** You have selected a six inch sub ****" << endl;

            sandCheck = halfSandwhich + sandSize;

        } else {
            cout << "**** You have selected a 12 inch sub ****" << endl;

            sandCheck = wholeSandwhich + sandSize;
        }
        return sandwhich;
    }
    string getSide() {
        string Appetizer;
        float side;
sides:
        cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Which appetizer would you like? ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n" << endl;
        cout << "1. Boneless Wings            .70\n2. BreadStix               $4.99\n\n" << endl;
        cout << "I would like the number:" << flush;
        cin >> side;
        while (side < 1 || side > 2) {
            cout << "\nINVAILD INPUT:\nEnter a Value that corresponds with your menu choice" << endl;
            goto sides;
        }
        if (side == 1) {
            cout << "\n**** You have selected Boneless wings ****\n" << endl;
            cout << "How many wings would you like?\n" << endl;
            cout << "I would like this many wings:" << flush;
            int wings;
            cin >> wings;
            cout << "\n**** You will recieve " << wings << " wings. ****" << endl;
            side = sideCheck;
            sideCheck = bonelessWings += sideCheck;
        } else {
            cout << "\n**** You have selected an order of breadstix ****" << endl;
            side = sideCheck;
            sideCheck = breadStix += sideCheck;
        }
        return Appetizer;
    }
    float addcheckout() {
        checkout = pizzaCheck;
        cout << "\nYour total is " << checkout << endl;
        cout << "\nThank You for your purchase!";
        return checkout;
    }




};
```

At the end of the program, when it gives the checkout total, it gives a value something like -1.07374e.+008

I am still learning how to code, and I am stumped on this one. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Had never seen `goto` for a long time! You should avoid using it, as it makes the code highly unreadable; specially as the code grows.

Answer (score 1):

I think you shadow your member field `pizzaCheck` in your method `getPizza`, so that you actually don‘t write to the member field but to your local var declared at the first line of that method.
Try removing that local var. (I did not test it yet though)